# How to using multi query usermeta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function user_in_query($user_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    $country_value = $_GET['country'];
    $city_value = $_GET['city'];
    $user_query->query_from  .= " JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS alias ON ($wpdb->users.ID = alias.user_id)";
    $user_query->query_from  .= " JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS alias2 ON ($wpdb->users.ID = alias2.user_id)";
    $user_query->query_where .= " AND alias.meta_key = 'country' AND alias.meta_value = '".$country_value."'";
    $user_query->query_where .= " AND alias2.meta_key = 'city' AND alias2.meta_value = '".$city_value."'";  
}
add_action('pre_user_query','user_in_query');
```

When I filter in url `wp-admin/users.php?country=US&city=Ohio` is result is not work, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I think `pre_user_query` is a filter, not an action.  So you'd need to change `add_action` to `add_filter`, and have your function return `$user_query`.

And please, please fix the [SQL injection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) vulnerability.